# Haskell calculator - order of operations

Tags: haskell, stack, calculator

I am very new to Haskell and I need to make a working calculator what will give answers to expressions like: 2+3*(5+12)
I have something that manages to calculate more or less but I have a problem with order of operations. I have no idea how to do it. Here is my code:

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
import Data.Maybe

oblicz :: String -> Double
oblicz str = eval (Nothing, None) $ map convertToExpression $ ( tokenize str )


eval :: (Maybe Double,Expression)->[Expression]->Double

eval (Nothing, _) ((Variable v):reszta) = eval (Just v, None) reszta
eval (Just aktualnyWynik, None) ((Operator o):reszta) = eval ((Just aktualnyWynik), (Operator o)) reszta



eval (Just aktualnyWynik, (Operator o)) ((Variable v):reszta) = eval (Just $ o aktualnyWynik v , None) reszta


eval (aktualnyWynik, operator) (LeftParenthesis:reszta) 
    = eval (aktualnyWynik, operator) ((Variable (eval (Nothing, None) reszta)):(getPartAfterParentheses reszta))


eval (Just aktualnyWynik, _) [] = aktualnyWynik
eval (Just aktualnyWynik, _) (RightParenthesis:_) = aktualnyWynik

data Expression =     Operator (Double->Double->Double)
                    | Variable Double
                    | LeftParenthesis
                    | RightParenthesis
                    | None

tokenize :: String -> [String]
tokenize expression = getAllTextMatches(expression =~ "([0-9]+|\\(|\\)|\\+|-|%|/|\\*)" :: AllTextMatches [] String)

convertToExpression :: String -> Expression                 
convertToExpression "-" = Operator (-)
convertToExpression "+" = Operator (+)
convertToExpression "*" = Operator (*)
convertToExpression "/" = Operator (/)
convertToExpression "(" = LeftParenthesis
convertToExpression ")" = RightParenthesis
convertToExpression variable = Variable (read variable)

getPartAfterParentheses :: [Expression] -> [Expression]
getPartAfterParentheses [] = []
getPartAfterParentheses (RightParenthesis:expressionsList) = expressionsList
getPartAfterParentheses (LeftParenthesis:expressionsList) = getPartAfterParentheses (getPartAfterParentheses expressionsList)
getPartAfterParentheses (expression:expressionsList) = getPartAfterParentheses expressionsList
```

I thought maybe I could create two stacks - one with numbers and one with operators. While reading the expression, I could push numbers on one stack and operators on another. When it is an operator I would check if there is something already on the stack and if there is check if I should pop it from the stack and do the math or not - just like in onp notation.

Unfortunately, as I said, I am VERY new to haskell and have no clue how to go about writing this.

Any hints or help would be nice :)

Comment: "This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself. "

Comment: Can you provide some example input and output? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: `LeftParenthesis` is not a `Expression`, it is only a parse token. Once you realize this, you will see the expression needs capturing in a different way (eg Tree like in the answers below), where precedence of operations will come up in a fairly straightforward manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing things on different stacks sure feels very much a prcedural thing to do, and that's generally not nice in Haskell. (Stacks can be realised as lists, which works quite nice in a purely functional fashion. Even real mutable state can be fine if only as an optimisation, but if more than one object needs to be modified at a time then this isn't exactly enjoyable.)

The preferrable way would be to build up a *tree* representing the expression.

```
type DInfix = Double -> Double -> Double  -- for readability's sake

data ExprTree = Op DInfix ExprTree ExprTree
              | Value Double
```

Evaluating this tree is basically `evalTree (Op c t1 t2) = c (evalTree t1) (evalTree t2)`, i.e. `ExprTree->Double` right away.

To build the tree up, the crucial point: get the *operator fixities* right. Different operators have different fixity. I'd put that information in the `Operator` field:

```
type Fixity = Int
data Expression = Operator (Double->Double->Double) Fixity
                | ...
```

which then requires e.g.

```
...
convertToExpression "+" = Operator (+) 6
convertToExpression "*" = Operator (*) 7
...
```

(Those are the fixities that Haskell itself has for the operators. You can `:i +` in GHCi to see them.)

Then you'd build the tree.

```
toExprTree :: [Expression] -> ExprTree
```

Obvious base case:

```
toExprTree [Variable v] = Value v
```

You might continue with

```
toExprTree (Variable v : Operator c _ : exprs) = Op c (Value v) (toExprTree exprs)
```

But that's actually not right: for e.g. `4 * 3 + 2` it would give `4 * (3 + 2)`. We actually need to bring the `4 *` down the remaining expressions tree, as deep as the fixities are lower. So the tree needs to know about that as well

```
data ExprTree = Op DInfix Fixity ExprTree ExprTree
              | Value Double

mergeOpL :: Double -> DInfix -> Fixity -> ExprTree -> ExprTree
mergeOpL v c f t@(Op c' f' t' t'')
   | c > c'  = Op c' f' (mergeOpL v c f t') t''
mergeOpL v c f t = Op c f (Value v) t
```

What remains to be done is handling parentheses. You'd need to take a whole matching-brackets expression and assign it a tree-fixity of, say `tight = 100 :: Fixity`.

---

As a note: such a tokenisation - manual parsing workflow is pretty cumbersome, regardless how nicely functional you do it. Haskell has powerful parser-combinator libraries like [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec), which take most of the work and bookkeeping off you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to solve this problem is the Shunting-yard Algorithm of Edsger Dijstra as described at http://www.wcipeg.com/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm.  You can see my implementation [at the bottom of this file](https://github.com/antarestrader/sapphire/blob/master/Eval.hs).

If you are limiting your self to just +,-,*,/ you can also solve the problem using the usual trick in most intro to compiler examples simply parsing into two different non-terminals, ofter called `term` and `product` to build the correct tree.  This get unwieldy if you have to deal with a lot of operators or they are user defined.